# Isolation of circuitry from heat source

Tags: dc, heat, isolation, electrode, electrolysis

I'm building an electrolysis unit which will comprise a refractory crucible, containing the electrolyte and the electrodes. The heat will be generated from a furnace to aid the desired reaction.

A direct current will flow in from a programmable power supply to the electrodes.

The problem I imagine I'll have is that heat from inside the crucible will be conducted through the electrodes and cabling and into the power supply.

Firstly, is this definitely an issue? I can't imagine the heat would conveniently stay in the crucible. Secondly, how's best to stop dangerous levels of heat feeding back into the electronics? I thought about galvanically isolating the crucible from the power supply by having a pulsed direct current run through a coil, with that then inducing a pulsed direct current in an adjacent coil connected to the electrodes. I can then smooth the pulses out using (passive components) in an RL circuit.

If a diagram would help, let me know.

Basically, just don't want to fry the power supply! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What diameter are the wires from the power supply to the hot region? Is the power supply in a separate room/enclosure that's kept cool?

Comment: The diameter of the wires carrying the current (up to 50A) to the electrodes will be 2 AWG. The power supply can be kept, within reason, as far from the crucible/electrolysis unit as possible. I was planning on having it about 10 feet away. All equipment will be outside.

Comment: You could wrap your 2AWG wires a few times around a metal rod with some heat sinks at the end for cooling. In which case it becomes a physics question, what Theta-j do you need to get rid of the heat? My gut feeling says you don't need much. (Make sure you wind the wires so they neutralize any magnetic field)

Comment: What temperature will the crucible/electrodes reach?

Comment: Will reach 700-800 Celsius. I'll be feeding gas into the crucible so I gather that wrapping cable around the canister will remove some of the heat conducted through the electrical cables and send it back into the crucible?

Comment: @Chris Make sure you don't use Al wires as they melt at about 660 °C. There's no diagram in the question showing the arrangement of the crucible and canister, but wrapping the cables around the canister is probably a bad idea. 10 feet of cables will dissipate the heat by the time they get to the power supply.

Comment: It's insulated copper, so should be fine. Thanks all!